# TextureAtlas.findRegions() how to find all parts of an animation?

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to load a set of frames from an atlas for an animation. After pack my images with TexturePacker, my atlas file is like this:

```
ufo_data2.png
size: 2048,2048
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0000
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0001
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 516
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0002
  rotate: false
  xy: 516, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0003
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 2
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0004
  rotate: false
  xy: 516, 516
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0005
  rotate: false
  xy: 1030, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red0006
  rotate: false
  xy: 516, 2
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

I'm trying to load the animation like this:

```
TextureAtlas atlas;
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/gfx/ufo_data.atlas"));
ufo_animation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.033f, atlas.findRegions("Ufo_gfx/red/"));
```

I found that `atlas.findRegions("Ufo_gfx/red/")` or even `atlas.findRegions("Ufo_gfx/red/*")` returns always 0 results.

I thought that using a Regex like expression will be enough to load all frames, but after look inside the findRegions() code, I found the only returns when match is exactly the string entered.

FindRegions() seems useless if one think in the way TexturePacker works.

My question is: is there a way to put an string that matches all names of images with a similar name?
Note: I found that the solution is here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#image-indexes

It is needed to put images with their name and underscore and index, like a_00.png
a_01.png
Then, texture packer packs images with indexes.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#image-indexes

Need to rename files as imagename_00.png, imagename_01.png, imagename_02.png.
When images are packaging, systems understands _xx as indices and automatically puts index in atlas file.

Then you only need to call findRegions(imagename)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function that calls `getRegion()`, iterates over all regions and checks whether their `name.startsWith("Ufo_gfx/red/")`. Put all these in a collection and return them from your helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple:

- All your regions should have the same name
- You should rewrite `index: -1` on all regions from -1 to count number from 1

How should it look like:

```
ufo_data2.png
size: 2048,2048
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 516
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 516, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 3
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 2
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 4
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 516, 516
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 5
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 1030, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 6
Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red
  rotate: false
  xy: 516, 2
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 7
```

Now you can create Array just using:

```
atlas.findRegions("Ufo_gfx/red/ufo_0_red");
```

Comment: Is like you explain, but there is an autmatic way to do that: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#image-indexes

Comment: @Killrazor TexturePacker does it automatically if you load them into folder before adding to TexturePacker.

Comment: As I had time to test, it doesn't if you don't put names in the correct format.

Comment: @Killrazor Your images should end with _N. Where N is index.

Answer (score 0):

All names of regions must be:

```
ufo_0_red_0001
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 1030
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
ufo_0_red_0002
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 516
  size: 512, 512
  .........
```